# Can I set different IP to second level sub-domain?

Tags: subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I'm trying to set a A records to this domain:
`*.mydomain.com A 1.1.1.1`
That will be different from this sub-domain:
`*.*.mydomain A 2.2.2.2`

But it's not working for me. And I always get the first IP when I ping it.
We're using AWS route 53 DNS

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide much more information. If you are using cpanel or the like your question will be closed. In general such a configuration is possible.

Comment: @MarkWagner We're using AWS Route 53

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to point sub-domains to different local IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/415780/how-to-point-sub-domains-to-different-local-ip)

Comment: @Overmind no. Thats not the same case

Comment: I can't find it right now, but IIRC you can't use multiple wildcards in a DNS record.

Answer (score 1):

DNS wildcards are discussed in RFCs [1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) and [4592](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4592). While neither document explicitly calls out the case of multiple wildcards, most interpretations seem to conclude that multiple wildcards are not permitted.

Beyond that, you'll have to ask AWS Route 53 for clarification of how they choose to interpret DNS wildcards.